RLDS/CofC Keys of the Kingdom
The Keys of the Kingdom are keys of authority given first to the apostle Peter (Mattew 16:18) and the Twelve (Matthew 18:19). Then, as part of the Restoration of All Things (Acts 3:19-21) they were restored “for the last time.” Joseph Smith subsequently passed these keys to Brigham Young and the Twelve, who went to Utah.
Smith said he would give the saints “keys that would never rust,” meaning they would endure forever. These keys are: If you follow the majority of the Twelve and the records of the church, you will NEVER be led astray.
How can the RLDS/CofC claim to be the true church that was restored to the Earth on April 6, 1830 when it has neither the Keys of Authority nor the Records of the Church?
How can it thus claim legal legitimacy?
